# The sum of two prime powers equal a third prime power.

Tags: prime-numbers

Is

$$13^2 + 7^3 = 512=2^9$$

the only solution for the sum of two primes $p,q$ raised to powers greater than $1$ equals a third prime power?

Comment: Well, there is $2^2+2^2=2^3$.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
2^5+7^2=3^4 
\end{eqnarray*}
There are other nice examples here ... http://people.math.sfu.ca/~ichen/pub/BeCh2.pdf

Comment: Since $1+1 \not \equiv 1\, \rm{mod}\, 2$, the problem is equivalent to find more solutions to $2^a = p^b \pm q^c$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. For instance, we have:

- $2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}$, for all $n$ meeting problem constraints; and
- $2^4+3^2=5^2$.

Comment: Aside  from the one with all 2s, it appears that my specimen is the only one to have the sum equal a power of 2.  I checked that PDF and NO other with sum being a power of 2.

Comment: The pdf answered my question.  Your site has been very helpful.  Do keep up the excellent assistance to the laity.

Answer (score 0):

You can check these types of numbers on wolfram alpha.

However you can see that $3^1+6^1=9^1$

Comment: It is  fair to say that 3 and 6 are not odd  primes to a power >1 and that 9 is not a power of 2.